# Lists stored as values in a dictionary of variable length - how to access all the last list items?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most efficient way to access **all** the last list items of lists stored in a dictionary? Please note that I am looking for a solution that works independently of the numbers of items in the dictionary.

As an example, here I would like to check if a number is higher than any of the last items in the lists. I think I got a solution but it seems convoluted and I am wondering if there is a better way.

```py
input_num = 5

lst_dct = {
    "lstA": [5, 12, 3, 4],
    "lstB": [2, 3, 7, 11],
    "lstC": [3, 8, 2, 20]
}

for key, value in lst_dct.items():
    if input_num < value[-1]:
        print("Input is **not** the highest.")
        break
else:
    print("Input is the highest.")
```

Returns correctly:

```
Input is **not** the highest.
```

Comment: Not really a good question for SO, since 1) you already have code that works and 2) there's nothing wrong with it. You could use `any()` and a generator expression instead, but that wouldn't really make the code any better.

Comment: No convolution here. It's easy to read the code and therefore understand the intent. Someone will probably come up with an impossible to understand one-liner but that isn't necessarily "better". [ I think your second 'lstB' was probably meant to be something else ]. You could just iterate over *values()* rather than *items()* as you don't need the keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close to optimal. You can replace the `items()` call with `values()` to save an unpacking and also shorten the code a bit, but that's it.

```py
if any(value[-1] >= input_num  for value in lst_dct.values()):
  print("Input is **not** the highest.")
else:
  print("Input is the highest.")
```